# File date metadata not displaying properly

Tags: datetime, powershell, com, metadata, powershell-3.0

I have been trying to write a Powershell script based on some [code online](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/08/13/how-can-i-find-files-metadata.aspx) that will read the metadata info from picture, video and other files and then sort them based on one of the dates (date taken currently seems to be the best bet if it's available, but date modified works on files that have not yet been altered).

However, when I run the script and pull the info, I can't convert the string to a date. Here's roughly how I get the info through a COM object:

```
PS C:/> $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
PS C:/> $objFolder = $objShell.namespace("C:\MyFolder")
PS C:/> $date = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFolder.Items().Item(0), 12)
PS C:/> $date

7/‎10/‎2014 ‏‎7:09 PM
```

The problem is I should be able to convert this to a datetime object. For instance, if I manually write it in it works:

```
PS C:/> [datetime]::ParseExact("7/10/2014 7:09 PM","g",$null)

Thursday, July 10, 2014 7:09:00 PM
```

But if I substitute the variable it doesn't work:

```
PS C:/> [datetime]::ParseExact($date,"g",$null)
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1
+ [datetime]::ParseExact($date,"g",$null)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

This is most likely due to the fact that the variable isn't actually what I'm seeing. It's in fact longer. Not to mention the fact that if you iterate through all the characters, you can see where the extra length is coming from:

```
PS C:\> $date.Length #should be about 16, you'd think

22

PS C:\> $datearray = @()
PS C:\> for ($i = 0; $i -lt $date.Length; $i++) {$datearray += $date[$i]}
PS C:\> $datearray #i'm printing on one line and in quotes for ease of viewing

" 7/ 10/ 2014   7:09 PM"
```

If you try printing the array with a join or something similar, the results are (to me, without knowing what's going on) unpredictable. It treats it like it has 22 characters, but prints ignoring the spaces.

I'm sure I could spend a bit of time and do some string formatting, but I'd rather just be able to parse the given date. What's going on?

Edit: I'm able to access the file info easily, though I prefer not to. I'm mainly focusing on why the results I'm seeing are inconstant and showing a length that doesn't match how it prints out, and how I can deal with them. If nothing else, I'm curious as to what is going on.

Comment: Any reason why you are using Shell.Application instead of relying on PowerShell for finding the modification date?

Comment: For the most part, it was because I was looking for a way to pull the metadata on the file, including the DateTaken field. It also looks like the date modified, created and accessed aren't quite what I'm looking for due to their inaccuracies. Created seems to be the date I copied it from my camera to my computer, modified is closest but only if I haven't done anything to the file (rotated, for example) and accessed seems to mirror date created.

Through my searches, the only way to get to the exif data on a picture or the metadata on a generic file was through this method.

Comment: Can't you use something like exiftags? http://johnst.org/sw/exiftags/

Comment: Also, for learning purposes. Exif works for image files I've found but only if windows can interpret it as a bitmap image (or something like that). When dealing with video files or raw files, it doesn't seem to work out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to know what the extra characters were ( you dont mention already looking at this. ). I Updated your array code `$datearray += $date[$i]` to `$datearray += [int][char]$date[$i]`. The *truncated* output showed two oddities `8207` and `8206` which translate to left-to-right mark and right-to-left mark. They are normally associated with html. Unfortunately i cannot provide insight to their presense. Good news is that they are easy to remove.

```
$date = ($date -replace [char]8206) -replace [char]8207
[datetime]::ParseExact($date,"g",$null)
```

Which nets the output

```
Thursday, March 26, 2009 1:43:00 PM
```

Hopefully this is a little bit closer of what you wanted. I tried searching for reasons for the presence of those ascii codes but i didn't find anything useful.

**Extra Information for other readers**

I did this since i didnt know what the index `12` was. So i made an array that contains the friendly names of all the file meta data possible (288 entries!). I have the here-string located [here](http://pastebin.com/hg5csbY0) for brevity.

With this i was testing the following code against a picture of mine.

```
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$objFolder = $objShell.namespace("C:\Temp\")
0..$Meta.GetUpperBound(0)| %{
    $metaValue = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFolder.Items().Item(2), $_)
    If ($metaValue) {Write-Host "$_ - $($meta[$_]) - $metaValue"}
    }
```

`$Meta` is the array i spoke of earlier. 
The code will cycle though all the details of my file, indicated by `Item(2)`, writing to screen all file details that contain values. In the end there is a line converting the string to a date value. Script output below

```
0 - Name - IMG_0571.JPG
1 - Size - 3.12 MB
2 - Item type - JPEG image
3 - Date modified - 3/26/2009 3:34 PM
4 - Date created - 8/24/2014 5:19 PM
5 - Date accessed - 8/24/2014 5:19 PM
6 - Attributes - A
9 - Perceived type - Image
10 - Owner - TE_ST\Cameron
11 - Kind - Picture
12 - Date taken - ‎3/‎26/‎2009 ‏‎1:43 PM
19 - Rating - Unrated
30 - Camera model - Canon EOS DIGITAL REBEL XS
31 - Dimensions - ‪3888 x 2592‬
32 - Camera maker - Canon
53 - Computer - TE_ST (this computer)
155 - Filename - IMG_0571.JPG
160 - Bit depth - 24
161 - Horizontal resolution - ‎72 dpi
162 - Width - ‎3888 pixels
....output truncated....
247 - Program mode - Normal program
250 - White balance - Auto
269 - Sharing status - Not shared
```

Comment: Very interesting. No, I hadn't looked in to what character it was, honestly I really should have though it simply didn't occur to me. Thanks, that certainly explains why it wasn't showing up as anything. I wonder if it was simply put there by the camera? Maybe this is a question for Nikon, in the end. Also, thanks for writing up the bit expanding on the metadata, that would have been nice to have when I first started learning this myself.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, `$objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFolder.Items().Item(0), 12)` I get an empty string. I even changed the item number and the folder I was looking in to make sure I was getting a file object.

However if I do this:

```powershell
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$objFolder = $objShell.namespace("C:\Temp")
$date = $objFolder.Items().Item(3).ModifyDate
```

I get a value that is already a `DateTime` object.

*(the code above uses my folder and item index)*

Comment: From what I can tell, getting the modify date from that is just the same as getting it from the generic file properties - while it's in a datetime format, it's still suffering from the inaccuracies issue if I edit the file at all. I'll update my question to explain a bit more, thanks!