# Shell.Application getDetailsOf jpg Exif DateTaken not valid DateTime

Tags: string, powershell, datetime, metadata

I'm using powershell to grab EXIF data from Jpg photos and I'm looking to get the Date Taken field then flip it to read `yyyy-MM-dd` which will become the name of a folder. The script source is listed below, for the full script check there.

The script below functions, but I get folders with the date format of `MM-dd-yyyy` and I get the feeling I'm missing something real simple. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

This question [File date metadata not displaying properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474023/file-date-metadata-not-displaying-properly) is exactly the behavior I've observed, the datetime string returned is 22 characters, I've tried to replace `[char]8206 and [char]8207` with `''` but that returns an error:

> Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not
>   recognized as a valid DateTime."
>   $NewDateFormat = [datetime]::ParseExact($DateTaken2, 'yyyy-MM-dd',$null)

```
#script source:
http://superwidgets.wordpress.com/category/powershell/
http://superwidgets.wordpress.com/2014/08/15/powershell-script-to-get-detailed-image-file-information-such-as-datetaken/
```

Script by Sam Boutros
v1.0 - 1/11/2015

```
$Images | ForEach-Object { $DateTaken = $_.DateTaken.Split(' ')[0].Replace('/','-')


    $DateTaken2 = ($DateTaken -replace [char]8206) -Replace([char]8207)

    $NewDateFormat = [datetime]::ParseExact($DateTaken2, 'yyyy-MM-dd',$null)

    IF (-not (Test-Path $Source\$DateTaken2)){"Create $Source\$DateTaken2"

    New-Item -Path "$Source\$DateTaken2" -ItemType Directory -Confirm:$false}

    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$Source\$DateTaken2" -Confirm:$false

    }
```

Comment: What precisely does `$_.DateTaken` contain when it errors out? IMO you'd better use a RegEx to filter the date elements to only numbers as long as the order is correct that isn't an issue.

Comment: I added `> file.log` to a few steps. Before the replace / with - then after the replace and after replacing [char]8206 and 8207. Here's the contents:
‎12/‎17/‎2017 ‏‎10:31 AM
‎12-‎17-‎2017
12-17-2017

Comment: Since `get-date ('12/‎17/‎2017 ‏‎10:31 AM' -replace [char]8206 -Replace [char]8207)` from above string returned a proper date here sodawillows answer looks promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the issue in your logic is that you give `ParseExact` the format 
that you want, instead of the format that you have in metadata. This method aims at creating a `DateTime` object from a string (based on the format you provide), not format a `DateTime` object.

You could try this instead (tested on a folder with 500 pics - remove `-WhatIf` for action):

```
$folderPath = "C:\UnsortedPics"

$newRootFolderPath = "C:\SortedPics"

# create root folder if does not exist
New-Item $newRootFolderPath -ItemType Directory -Force -WhatIf | Out-Null

# create shell object
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

# create folder object
$folder = $shell.NameSpace($folderPath)

foreach ($file in $folder.Items()) {

    # get raw date from file metadata
    $rawDate = ($folder.GetDetailsOf($file, 12) -replace [char]8206) -replace [char]8207

    if ($rawDate) {
        try {
            # parse to date object
            $date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($rawDate, "g", $null)

            # you could also use this without try/catch:
            #$date = New-Object Datetime
            #$parseSuccess = [DateTime]::TryParseExact($rawDate, "g", (Get-Culture), [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, [ref]$date)

            # get wanted format
            $dateString = Get-Date $date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

            # create path
            $newFolderPath = Join-Path $newRootFolderPath $dateString

            # create folder if does not exist
            New-Item $newFolderPath -ItemType Directory -Force -WhatIf | Out-Null

            # move file
            Move-Item $file.Path -Destination $newFolderPath -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
        } catch {
            # ParseExact failed (would also catch New-Item errors)
        }
    } else {
        # no value for "Date Taken" property
    }

}
```

With this approach, you don't need the TechNet script anymore :).

Comment: Lost track of this! Need to find free time to re-test this!

Comment: Ended up trimming down this answer into a compact script, works a treat! Thanks!