# Unable to get string Property of Item and convert it to Int

Tags: powershell

```bsh
# Solution by @BACON (I changed the following lines in the code)

[convert]::ToInt32(($_.$widthProperty.split(' ')[0] -replace [char]8206), 10)
[convert]::ToInt32(($_.$heightProperty.split(' ')[0] -replace [char]8206), 10)
```

I'm trying to convert the string values of the Property called 'Breedte' (Width in English) and 'Hoogte' (Height in English) to Integers so I can compare them. However when I try to convert them, they return nothing. The weird thing is it does work with the Property 'Grootte' (Size in English) using the same method.

Thanks in advance

Here's my Powershell script:

```bsh
$threshold = 160 # size in kB

# Config for Property names (Translations)
$nameProperty = 'Naam';
$widthProperty = 'Breedte';
$heightProperty = 'Hoogte';
$sizeProperty = 'Grootte';

Clear-Host

# Get all files
Get-FileMetaData 'C:\Users\Anton\Pictures\StackOverflow' | Select-Object -Property Breedte, Hoogte, Grootte, @{
        Name = 'Name'
        Expression = {
            $_.$nameProperty
        }}, @{
        Name = 'Width'
        Expression = {
            [convert]::ToInt32($_.$widthProperty.split(' ')[0], 10)
        }}, @{
        Name = 'Height'
        Expression = {
            [convert]::ToInt32($_.$heightProperty.split(' ')[0], 10)
        }}, @{
        Name = 'Size'
        Expression = {
            [convert]::ToInt32($_.$sizeProperty.split(' ')[0], 10)
        }}
```

Here's the function Get-FileMetaData that I use in this script:

```bsh
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# Script: Get-FileMetaDataReturnObject.ps1 
# Author: ed wilson, msft 
# Date: 01/24/2014 12:30:18 
# Keywords: Metadata, Storage, Files 
# comments: Uses the Shell.Application object to get file metadata 
# Gets all the metadata and returns a custom PSObject 
# it is a bit slow right now, because I need to check all 266 fields 
# for each file, and then create a custom object and emit it. 
# If used, use a variable to store the returned objects before attempting 
# to do any sorting, filtering, and formatting of the output. 
# To do a recursive lookup of all metadata on all files, use this type 
# of syntax to call the function: 
# Get-FileMetaData -folder (gci e:\music -Recurse -Directory).FullName 
# note: this MUST point to a folder, and not to a file. 
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Function global:Get-FileMetaData 
{ 
  <# 
   .Synopsis 
    This function gets file metadata and returns it as a custom PS Object  
   .Description 
    This function gets file metadata using the Shell.Application object and 
    returns a custom PSObject object that can be sorted, filtered or otherwise 
    manipulated. 
   .Example 
    Get-FileMetaData -folder "e:\music" 
    Gets file metadata for all files in the e:\music directory 
   .Example 
    Get-FileMetaData -folder (gci e:\music -Recurse -Directory).FullName 
    This example uses the Get-ChildItem cmdlet to do a recursive lookup of  
    all directories in the e:\music folder and then it goes through and gets 
    all of the file metada for all the files in the directories and in the  
    subdirectories.   
   .Example 
    Get-FileMetaData -folder "c:\fso","E:\music\Big Boi" 
    Gets file metadata from files in both the c:\fso directory and the 
    e:\music\big boi directory. 
   .Example 
    $meta = Get-FileMetaData -folder "E:\music" 
    This example gets file metadata from all files in the root of the 
    e:\music directory and stores the returned custom objects in a $meta  
    variable for later processing and manipulation. 
   .Parameter Folder 
    The folder that is parsed for files  
   .Notes 
    NAME:  Get-FileMetaData 
    AUTHOR: ed wilson, msft 
    LASTEDIT: 01/24/2014 14:08:24 
    KEYWORDS: Storage, Files, Metadata 
    HSG: HSG-2-5-14 
   .Link 
     Http://www.ScriptingGuys.com 
 #Requires -Version 2.0 
 #> 
 Param([string[]]$folder) 
 foreach($sFolder in $folder) 
  { 
   $a = 0 
   $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
   $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($sFolder) 

   foreach ($File in $objFolder.items()) 
    {  
     $FileMetaData = New-Object PSOBJECT 
      for ($a ; $a  -le 266; $a++) 
       {  
         if($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a)) 
           { 
             $hash += @{$($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a))  = 
                   $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a)) } 
            $FileMetaData | Add-Member $hash 
            $hash.clear()  
           } #end if 
       } #end for  
     $a=0 
     $FileMetaData 
    } #end foreach $file 
  } #end foreach $sfolder 
} #end Get-FileMetaData
```

This is a list of the properties I use, as you can see the Width and the Height don't have a value.

```
Breedte : ‎1920 pixels
Hoogte  : ‎1080 pixels
Grootte : 388 kB
Name    : sunset.jpg
Width   : 
Height  : 
Size    : 388
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File date metadata not displaying properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474023/file-date-metadata-not-displaying-properly).  The values of `$_.$widthProperty` and `$_.$heightProperty` begin with a Unicode 8206 character ([left-to-right mark](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark)), which prevents `[Convert]::ToInt32()` from working.  This is an artifact of calling `GetDetailsOf()`.

Comment: Thanks, Anton, glad to hear it. The crucial part of your question is the use of `New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application` and the resulting object's `. getDetailsOf()` method. Generally, please don't edit solutions into _questions_; instead, [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), if appropriate - though that is neither possible nor necessary here, given that your question is a duplicate. As an aside: a simplification would be `[int] ($_.$widthProperty.split(' ')[0] -replace [char]8206)` or `[int] ($_.$widthProperty.split(' ')[0] -replace '\D')`